# Listen on multiple ports for socket server

Tags: php, sockets

I have a php socket server. It's pretty advanced (IMO, haha) and I was wondering if I could make it listen on not one, but two or more ports? For example, let's say I currently have it listening on 6112. I now want it to ALSO listen on 6113. You could easily say just run the script twice, with different ports, but I don't want that. I have another class that handles the server properties, like users (which is another class per user, with user properties as well), etc. I want the user to think they're on the same server and I want them to see the users from both ports (6112, 6113) and everything. so basically I want both sockets to share the same server properties and user properties and I want them both to update.

Comment: *just ask for clarification

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use `socket_select()` to listen for input on multiple sockets.

Answer (score 2):

Open multiple sockets, each bound to a different port. Put them in an array and use `socket_select()` to wait for connections on any of them.