# PHP How to listen on multiple tcp ports

Tags: php, sockets, port

I'm not quite sure if this is possible and searching on here + google did not help. I want to listen on two ports(lets for example use 6113 and 6114) I want these two to be listened on by the same script but not run on different scripts. So I want to be able to connect on 6113 and 6114 but using the same script. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Nope it does not. Usually PHP doesn't do any listening at all. You've got a web server that listens an handles the request. That server just calls PHP to generate some output. So I think you are looking in the wrong place to configure this.

Comment: Did you try it and it did not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975276/listen-on-multiple-ports-for-socket-server

Comment: I have a TCP server coded in php and I want that to listen on multiple ports.

Comment: Well then, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Like GolezTrol. I'm confused by your question.

> I want these two to be listened on

So your script is a server?

> I want to be able to connect on 6113 and 6114 but using the same script

So your script is the client?

Assuming you really want a server, then you need to think about the protocol and how you're going to handle simultaneous connections from multiple clients. The simplest way to solve both problems would be using an event based server ([socket_select](https://www.php.net/socket-select)() or [stream_select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php)()).

It's a messy solution - a simpler approach would be to redirect the port at the OS layer (e.g. using iptables on Linux) then you've only got one listening port to worry about.

While you can also use [socket_select](https://www.php.net/socket-select)() and [stream_select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php)() to manage multiple client connections it's probably overkill - depending on the protocol. the curl_multi functions would be easier.